# Why did I get an "Enlightened" badge?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, enlightened-badge

I logged into SO this morning and was notified that I received an "Enlightened" badge. 
The only answer of mine that was accepted since when I had logged in last (yesterday evening) was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334496/difference-between-ui-and-ux/1334516#1334516), which was indeed accepted, but has only five upvotes. 
Now, I'm a fan of having silver badges and all, but it seems to me like this one was awarded erroneously. Is this a bug?

Comment: As others have mentioned, badges can be awarded to community-wiki posts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why did I get an Enlightened Badge?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24621/why-did-i-get-an-enlightened-badge)

Comment: @JosephWeissman That question describes a different situations; answers from there do not apply here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[You have an accepted answer with 37 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245430/over-the-last-7-8-years-what-are-the-biggest-influences-on-c-programming/1245443#1245443). Moreover, it was the first answer to that question. That's the definition of the enlightened badge. Yes, badges apply to community wiki answers.

Comment: Ah ok... Didn't realize that one had been accepted too. *facepalm* Thanks guys

Comment: You're so silly, Donut. I'm going to eat you, you delicious deep-fried  sugar-coated pastry. Did you know I'm a donutomologist? I'm going to eat you **for science**!

Comment: You're so crazy, Welbog, I might have to write a bog post about you on the interwel. For **justice**.

Comment: But I've already written about you, Donut! http://welbog.homeip.net/glue/49/Donutomology You are my favourite thing to eat!

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245430/over-the-last-7-8-years-what-are-the-biggest-influences-on-c-programming/1245443#1245443) is most likely the culprit, given that it has 37 upvotes. Badges, but not rep, are awarded for CW answers and questions.

Also, the badges are not awarded real time. There's a scheduled stored procedure that goes out and rewards them. What you experienced as a delay in the acceptance and the reward.

Comment: You're a scheduled stored procedure that goes out and awards badges!

Comment: It's true, I am. However did you discover my secret?!

Answer (score 1):

You have 1 enlightened badge; I guess it is for [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245430/over-the-last-7-8-years-what-are-the-biggest-influences-on-c-programming/1245443#1245443), then. Not bad for a 1-word answer ;-p