# Why did I get an Enlightened Badge?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, enlightened-badge

I received an Enlightened Badge when I logged into stackoverflow.com today. While this is nice, I don't understand why.

I have two answers with more than 10 upvotes, but none of them was the first answer to the question.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Is is possible an earlier answer was deleted recently?

Comment: Both questions still have earlier answers.

Comment: You have an accepted answer with a score of 7. Any chance it had three downvotes?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it didn't get any downvotes. If that were the case, I should also have a "Nice Answer" badge for that question, which I don't.

Comment: It seems to be this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255/54434#54434 but it was hardly the first answer.

Comment: If it were that answer, the badge should have been awarded on 2009/09/27

Comment: It is ironic that an 'Enlightened' badge should cause such confusion.

Comment: The only thing that makes sense to me here is that you answered a question, your answer was accepted, up-voted 10 times... and then the question was deleted. But I can't find any evidence of this, so who knows? Unless a SO moderator (who can see deleted answers on user profiles) can back this up, I would certainly consider this a bug!

Comment: Perhaps an answer was unaccepted after the badge was awarded?

Comment: @Jon: but, he still has only 2 answers with >= 10 votes... neither first, both accepted, neither recently.

Comment: I've got guru, but I don't know to what answer :-/

Comment: `Guru` is really easy. Just look for answers voted +40 or more that are accepted.

Comment: @afk: enlightenment is always confusing to the unenlightened. (it's frequently confusing to the enlightened as well.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Definitely a mystery. You shouldn't have the badge; our current SQL queries agree.

- I suspected "accepted answer changed" hijinks, but you have no other answers with >= 10 score, and the two you do, are already accepted. So that can't be it.
- I suspected deleted answers but you don't have any.
- I suspected downvotes (was it at +10 then voted down?), but but you have exactly one.

One possibility: a question could be merged into another, which means a previously "top" accepted answer wouldn't be chronologically first any more. But again it'd have to have +10 score and would still be associated with your user.

The queries, when running now, show that you should NOT have this badge. But the queries haven't changed in months, so **at the time the query was run and the badge was awarded, *something* was different**. But I can't figure out what that was.

Hrm.

Comment: Maybe the boogie monster or worse, Jon Skeet hacked your database a while ago. Spooky.

Comment: Perhaps it's time to add comprehensive auditing trail to the badge calculator.  There are enough badges (and more to come no doubt) that it will be impossible to completely debug them without this information.

Comment: Why is this no longer [meta-tag:status-review] but [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Answer (score 2):

The only recent activity I can see in terms of reputation is for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48475) - you received a vote on Saturday (2 days ago, which is when you got the badge).

However, that's your *question* rather an answer... which suggests that one of the following has happened:

- You were awarded it for a migrated answer (unlikely - not many migrations *to* SO)
- You were awarded it for a CW answer - except you don't have any, as far as I can see
- The system is broken somewhere - possible: this does look quite odd...