# Suddenly being awarded enlightened badges?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, notifications

I seem to have gotten 4 enlighted badges in the last hour, without that many upvotes/accepts on my answers.

I expect these to be awarded closer to when the conditions are met (first answer accepted with 10 upvotes).

Is this happening to others?

What is going on? Is there some batch job that is going back to old questions/answers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Someone please call 911... Silver badges missing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66268/someone-please-call-911-silver-badges-missing)

Comment: @ChrisF - he was asking about _missing_ badges, I am asking about getting _awarded_ unexpected ones. I suspect both have the same root cause :)

Comment: If you read @waffles' answer you'll see that it is the same problem.

Comment: @ChrisF is correct, it was the same problem.  You were awarded them because they were taken away, then given back during the next badge grant process.  Same thing happened to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a glitch in the matrix, we had a long standing bug where tons of people got the enlightened badge for the wrong reason.

We fixed that bug about a month ago.

Since then the system stopped assigning badges incorrectly and was waiting for the real badge count to catch up with the one users had in the badges table.

Some lucky people kept on getting enlightened badges, other less lucky ones felt like all sorts of enlightened answers were being skipped. This was causing lots of confusion and made my life really tough.

So I **recalculated the enlightened badge** for all users on all sites today, wacked out the invalid reasons and put in correct ones instead. This caused quite a few people to get annoying you got the enlightened badge notifications, I fixed that as well just now.

For the record, it would have taken Jon Skeet about 8 days to catch up to his real badge count if I did not accelerate the process (and that would be one week of annoying you got the enlightened badge messages)

Comment: "Huh.  Deja Vu..."

Comment: So wait... it just told me I earned six of them overnight, but does that mean that I already had them before and my count is unchanged?

Comment: @mmyers It looks that way; you have [28 in the last data dump](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/11978/) and [29 on SO right now](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/19/enlightened?userid=13531); it looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899670/jframe-in-java/899682#899682) is the one new one (the data dump is from 31 Aug, and you got that one 2 Sep)

Comment: I've seen this message twice today. My current number of enlightened badges is 13, but I believe that I've only had 12 the last time that message appeared. (Some hours ago.) Both badges were for question that had already 21 upvotes.

Comment: @waffles, how long is it taking for the badge to be awarded?  I think I am eligible for my first ;)

Comment: @hvgotocodes ... max you should have to wait is an hour or two ...

Answer (score 1):

I received this message as well.

I believe there was some kind of error made in assigning badges.  I had 15 bronze badges before I received this message, and now have 14 which is the correct number AFAIK.

I realize that the enlightened badge is not a bronze badge, but the message did indeed say that I had received the enlightened badge.

I have not in the past few weeks or so received any votes that would have qualified me for an enlightened badge.

I would think that this recalculation, if it should be called such, would be posted on the blog soon.