# Badges from nowhere

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, enlightened-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suddenly being awarded enlightened badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66286/suddenly-being-awarded-enlightened-badges)

Over the last 9 hours I've received six enlightment badges, but no votes or accepted answers on any of the questions involved.  If it helps, here are the questions involved:

[Closures and Lambda in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306947/)
[.NET / C# - Convert char[] to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324009/)
[How could I improve this C# randomising method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627064/)
[Can't create static variable inside a static method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646092/)
[How do closures work behind the scenes? (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928636/)
[App.Config vs. AppName.exe.Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916023/)

A check looks like I do deserve the badge for each of these questions.  I just wonder whether I'm getting a duplicate award or a duplicate notification.

Comment: Similar issue... how can you get the enlightened badge more than once? http://stackoverflow.com/badges/19/enlightened?userid=20471

Comment: @Joe: The "first answer" refers to the first answer posted to some question. So for every question there is the potential that the user that posted the first answer gets an enlightened badge.